# how to include integer fields in searchkick search?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, searchkick

I use the following code to search using SearchKick:

```
Book.search(q, 
            misspellings: { below: 5 }, 
            fields: [:name, :author, :pages], 
            order: { name: 'asc' }, 
            page: params[:page], 
            per_page: 20)
```

When I search `name` and `author` it works fine.

However, when I search `130` for `page` it doesn't search the field.

`name` and `author` are string fields of a Book model, and `page` is an integer field.

My guess is the `130` is coming through as a string, and it is incorrectly trying to match the integer.

How can I make it so that I can search based on page numbers?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried calling `to_i` on `params[:page]`?

```
Book.search(q, 
            misspellings: { below: 5 }, 
            fields: [:name, :author, :pages], 
            order: { name: 'asc' }, 
            page: params[:page]&.to_i, 
            per_page: 20)
```

If you're right and it is comparing integer to string, this would fix it.

Comment: sorry i tried it and not working. I went to console and just searched Book.search(120, fields: [:pages]) and it returns empty result even though there are records with pages 120. Why is searchkick not searching for integer fields?

Comment: Unless it's the other way round and it's looking for strings both sides? Could you give this a quick shot in the console `Book.search("120", fields: [:pages])`?